# How do I change sql 'like' operator dynamically?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, oracle11g

In my following code I want to dynamically database content retrieve. But problem is final condition. How should I change?

```
    string qry= "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where";
    For(i=0;i<arraylenth;i++)
    {
    qry+= " Data_sentences like '%" + array[i].tostring() + "%' OR";
    }qry += " 1=1";
```

In this code final condition 1=1 got wrong. All sentences retrieve. How should I changed to get expected sentences only?

Comment: Its not strange that it retrieves everything, since you are doing an OR 1=1, in an OR statement, if anything is true, the whole statement is true, and 1==1 is always true, so no matter whats before, your whole statement will be true

Comment: @Pienterekaak yep thanx for explanation. I should add there 1=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to `1=0`:

```
string qry= "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where";
For(i=0;i<arraylenth;i++)
{
qry+= " Data_sentences like '%" + array[i].tostring() + "%' OR";
}qry += " 1=0";
```

Use `1=1` when the connector is `AND`.

Comment: @Maduri Whilst this might provide the functionality desired, it doesn't address the evident lack of understanding, or the other issues that are evident with the code. I would suggest the more thorough answer which around the same time as this (By @JonK), would be a better reference if you trully want to fix your code. :) - Also the above code still won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code that you have posted.

- Raw `String` concatenation inside a loop is **very bad**. Use a `StringBuilder` (or a `StringBuffer` if thread safety is required) to do it instead.
- `OR 1 = 1` will always be true, so every single row will meet the criteria and be returned.

There are a few options open to you, here are some of them:

```java
StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder(
        "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 WHERE 1 = 1");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        qry.append(" AND (Data_sentences LIKE '%" + array[i].toString() + "%'");
    } else {
        qry.append(" OR Data_sentences LIKE '%" + array[i].toString() + "%'");
    }

    if (i == array.length - 1) {
        qry.append(")");
    }
}
```

This one moves the `1 = 1` condition into the base string, because it will always be appended anyway. It also alters the form of your `OR` conditions, producing a query such as (formatted for ease of reading):

```sql
SELECT Data_Sentences
  FROM table1
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND (Data_Sentences LIKE '%some value%'
        OR Data_Sentences LIKE '%some other value%')
```

Obviously the format of this query is different from your original one, but should function in the same way. Alternatively, you could do this:

```java
StringBuilder qry = new StringBuilder(
        "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 WHERE");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    qry.append(" Data_sentences LIKE '%" + array[i].toString() + "%' OR");
}
qry.append(" 1 = 0");
```

Which would produce something very similar to your current query (again formatted for ease of reading):

```sql
SELECT Data_Sentences
  FROM table1
 WHERE Data_Sentences LIKE '%some value%'
    OR Data_Sentences LIKE '%some other value%'
    OR 1 = 0
```

I haven't performed any tests to see which of the queries would be more efficient, but if I had to guess I would say that the query with fewer `OR`s in it would be the faster of the two, but the difference (if any) would be negligible.

A third option would be to check the length of `array` first, and skip the `WHERE` clause completely if it's of size `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If would make more sense not to have this funny 1=1 or 1=0 dummy condition.

```
string qry= "SELECT Data_Sentences FROM table1 Where";
For(i=0;i<arraylenth;i++)
{
    qry+= " Data_sentences like '%" + array[i].tostring() + "%'";
    if (i < arraylenth-1)
        qry+= " OR";
}
```

Comment: The point of the dummy condition is so that if arrayLength is zero, the SQL query won't be left in an invalid state. It's quite common practice to do, but it's usually the first condition, not tacked onto the end. It also allows you to not care about whether you need a WHERE or an AND if you're dynamically building up the entire query if you can rely on there always being a `WHERE 1 = 1` condition present.

Comment: Holy crap, is that why people do this? I have seen this from time to time and never knew. That is a horrible reason to mess up an SQL.

Comment: @nablex I agree, it's ugly. But it's also much easier than parsing the whole query to find out whether you need to tack on an AND or a WHERE (I've experienced both). Ugly or not, I'd take the dummy condition over a full parse any day of the week.

Comment: I have built many sqls programmatically and even built an SQL modeler that would spit out hundreds of lines of SQL. Never once parsed the SQL to check if I should add something. Not only is it ugly, it is completely unnecessary.